# Python Automatic browser without webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have this code , it opens chrome, but it doesn't want to continue with the code. Don't really know how to fix the issue. I do NOT want it to open selenium webdriver, want it to open my own local chrome path, I want at the same time to make the script to read read elements and print the values.

[image: Error picture]

```
import names, time, random
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC




def AccGen():
        while True:

            # *************Static***************
            prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 1}
            options = Options()
            # options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
            # options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
            # options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
            options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
            options.add_argument("--window-size=1600,900")
            browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/Jonathan/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/Application/Chrome.exe',chrome_options=options)
            browser.implicitly_wait(10)

            # ------------------------------------

            # Access to site
            browser.get(
                "https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ltmpl=default"
            )

            ###################################################################

            firstName = names.get_first_name()
            lastName = names.get_last_name()
            email = '{}.{}{}'.format(firstName, lastName, random.randint(1000, 9999))
            password = '2001jl00'

            ###################################################################
            # Write in random Name
            WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                    (By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstName"]'))).send_keys(firstName)
```

https://mystb.in/vevivuneku.coffeescript

Comment: From the error I think you need to change `chrome_options` to `options`.

Comment: Did not make any changes sadly, but thank you doe your input

Comment: what error you got when you changed to `options`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Also, the core of the code in question should be *in the question itself.* You can keep the link to show the full script (but it's not really that long).

Comment: if you don't want to use chromedriver, you'll need to create your own application which launches chrome.  Once you launch Chrome you can hook into it.

Comment: the same error as before, just without the chrome_

Comment: thank you @pcalkins! but can you explain a little bit more please, fairly new to programming

Comment: not familiar with python, but I found this:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#browser-controller-objects  You should be able to register python methods with a particular web page if you wanted to communicate between the page and your script.  A lot of programs will embed a browser inside of them for a convenient UI.

Comment: btw, if you just want to read the page, I'm not sure why you are avoiding the Selenium API for doing that.  (or Curl or something like that...)  Can you explain that, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: thank you for the link, will test it out! I don't want to use it since it blocks out the script on the site sadly.